# How to handle multiple asynchronous inside of IntentService

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, service

I am writing an application that does multiple downloads of JSON data from multiple sources. Each of the downloads is done asynchronously with a callback method.

My idea is to use a IntentService, since I want all of the handling of data to be run on the same thread, and call all of the asynchronous downloads at the same time. But since a IntentService stops once it finishes running onHandleIntent, won't, how can I make it wait for all of the asynchronous downloads to finish?  This is how my onHandleIntent method would look

```
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       asyncTaskAWithCallback{
            //some handling of data
       }
       asyncTaskBWithCallback{
            //some handling of data
       }

       ...

       asyncTaskNWithCallback{
            //some handling of data
       }
       //Some code to wait for all callbacks to finish?
  }
```

Comment: I would recommend that you create your own `Service` with your own thread management, where you can implement your own rules better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `Service` instead of a `IntentService` just like CommonWare suggested in a comment. Following this [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService) and putting the handling of data inside of separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

add a loop waiting for a counter to reach the value of your asyncs count
and let each async increase this count onPost

Comment: this did not work unfortunately, the async callback was never called.

Comment: how come it never called !

Comment: are you sure you called async.execute() ??

Comment: Yeah i'm sure. I have no idea why, I am guessing some threading issue?

Comment: post some code so we might be able to figure it out